# How can I add across multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add the same cell across multiple sheets in a single workbook. A few parameters:

- The cell will always be the same (A4)
- I'm not sure how many sheets I will have every month.
- It is stored as a number?

I've tried googling this, and it always had a simple sum formula. I'm looking to specifically write a VBA function to do it.

```
Function AddAcrossSheets(rng As Range) As Variant

    valRow = rng.Row
    valCol = rng.Column


    For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
        AddAcrossSheets = Sheets(x).Cells(valRow, valCol).Value + AddAcrossSheets
    Next x


End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you just create an end tab and a start tab, and write a cell formula that will sum the sandwich, e.g. '=SUM(Start:End!A4)'

Comment: Note: this code will blow up with error 438 if any of the `Sheets` is actually a `Chart`. Consider iterating the `Worksheets` collection instead, ...and qualifying it with an explicit `Workbook` object reference, e.g. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

Answer (score 0):

Remember, always add `Option Explicit` on the very top of your code. This will force you to declare all your variables, which in turn will save you from all kinds of trouble.

That's how i'd do it

```
Sub addAcrossSheets()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim totalSum As Double
totalSum = 0 'initialize the sum
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through the collection of worksheets
    totalSum = totalSum + sht.Range("A4") 'update the sum
Next sht
Debug.Print totalSum 'the result is displayed in your immediate window
End Sub
```

Now, you might want to exclude some worksheets from the sum. You could do that like so:

```
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through the collection of worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Something" And sht.Name <> "Something else" Then 'exclude worksheets from the sum
        totalSum = totalSum + sht.Range("A4") 'update the sum
    End If
Next sht
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's always the same location (A4) then you can just hard code it in.

```
valueFromA4 = Cells(4, 1).Value

For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Cells(4, 1).Value = valueFromA4
Next i
```

I recommend using i in your for loop, just a convention. Most loops begin with i = 0, but with Excel Sheets begin with a count of 1, so the sheet after your first sheet will be 2.

Comment: To be safe, I'd do `Dim valueFromA4 as String`, to make sure Excel doesn't set `valueFromA4` as a `Range`. (...hm, it may not matter the way you're using it, but better to be explicit)

Comment: Yes it depends on how you want to use it. If you want a String value from the cell you can Dim it as a String and use Cells(4, 1).value2, which abstracts the value with no formatting.